# Spring boot JPA foreign key variable can not read data from mysql db

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I'm creating two tables for users and companies, multiple users can belong to one company, so it is a many-to-one relationship. But for some reason, the company_id foreign key variable can not extract data from the Company table(please see the screenshot below). I have been googling for some time but fail to find any solution. Would really appreciate your help.

[image]

UserEntity.java

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class UserEntity extends DateAudit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6622427995561357149L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private CompanyEntity company; //can not extract data

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ItemEntity> safetyPlans;  //but this works
}
```

CompanyEntity.java

```
@Entity(name = "Companies")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class CompanyEntity extends DateAudit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6622427995561357151L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyId;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, String>, IUserRepository {
    Optional<UserEntity> findOneById(UUID id);
    Optional<UserEntity> findByUsername(String username);
    List<UserEntity> findAll();
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override   
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity entity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));
        return new User(entity.getUsername(), entity.getPassword(), emptyList());
    }
}
```

companies table

[image]

users table

[image]

Error log when want to read the value(e.g. entity.getCompany().getName()):

```
2021-09-10 17:29:02.747 ERROR 88245 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.a.m.auth.JWTAuthenticationFilter       : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not initialize proxy [com.ahurufoundation.management.data.mysql.entity.user.CompanyEntity#1] - no Session
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
ProviderManager.java:182
    at com.ahurufoundation.management.auth.JWTAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:41) ~[main/:na]
JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:41
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
LogoutFilter.java:103
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
LogoutFilter.java:89
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
CorsFilter.java:91
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
HeaderWriterFilter.java:90
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
HeaderWriterFilter.java:75
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:336
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
FilterChainProxy.java:211
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:189
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:162
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
RequestContextFilter.java:100
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:189
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:162
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
FormContentFilter.java:93
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:189
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:162
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
OncePerRequestFilter.java:119
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:189
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ApplicationFilterChain.java:162
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
StandardWrapperValve.java:202
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
StandardContextValve.java:97
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
AuthenticatorBase.java:542
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
StandardHostValve.java:143
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
ErrorReportValve.java:92
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
StandardEngineValve.java:78
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
CoyoteAdapter.java:346
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
Http11Processor.java:374
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
AbstractProcessorLight.java:65
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
AbstractProtocol.java:887
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
NioEndpoint.java:1684
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
SocketProcessorBase.java:49
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
TaskThread.java:61
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Thread.java:748
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.ahurufoundation.management.data.mysql.entity.user.CompanyEntity#1] - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
ProxyConfiguration.java:95
    at com.ahurufoundation.management.data.mysql.entity.user.CompanyEntity$HibernateProxy$FN6IM1Ba.getName(Unknown Source) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ahurufoundation.management.auth.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:33) ~[main/:na]
UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:33
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: thanks for your note, unfortunately, I don't really know how to copy text of variables at breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the many to one relationship you need to specify the referenced column name:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CompanyEntity company; //can not extract data
```

just like you would do in a join sql query

Also make sure whenever you try to access the company field from the UserEntity object you have an open session (you are in a transactional context) because it is loaded lazily (only loaded when accessed)

Be aware that unless you call: `userEntity.getCompany()` the company object will not be initialized, that's what lazy loading means. It only loads the object from the database if it's accessed.

And the most important! You need to call the `userEntity.getCompany()` in a transactional context so that you have an open session (annotate the method that finds the user and calls the getter with `@Transactional`)

**Example (bad):**

```
@Override   
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    // the call to user.getCompany() will throw the same error because as soon as the
    // findByUsername returns the session is closed
    CompanyEntity company = user.getCompany();
}
```

this example will throw the same error because as soon as the findByUsername returns the session is closed.

**Example (good):**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    CompanyEntity company = user.getCompany();
}
```

Now here the session will only get closed after leaving the `loadUserByUsername` method so inside you'll have an active session

**RULE:** Every time you have a lazy association if you want to be able to load it you need to have an open session (a session is always opened when a transaction starts)

Comment: could you show us the code with which you try to read the data?

Comment: And what's the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: exception throws when i tried to read the value inside. log added.

Comment: If you check my answer you'll see that you need to be in a transaction to be able to do that because of the lazy loading. (read my last 2 paragraphs from the answer)

Comment: You are right, I have to annotate it with transactional. Although it still shows null values in debug window it actually can read the variables by calling get...(). maybe it is more an IDE problem(Im using VSCode). But thank you very much for being so patient.